# Scala List into Seq

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a scala code like this

```
val tokens = List("the", "program", "halted")
val test = for (c <- tokens) yield Seq(c)
```

Here test is returning List(Seq(String)) but I'm expecting Seq(String) only. Maybe it's very simple for an experienced person but I tried all the way which I know in the basic level but no look. Please help me if anyone feels its very easy.

Comment: You are traversing a list of strings, transforming each into a singleton sequence containing just that string, thereby producing a list of singleton sequences of strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tokens.toSeq` will do, but if you type this into the command line you will see that `Seq` will just create a `List` under the hood anyway:

```
scala> val tokens = List("the", "program", "halted")
tokens: List[String] = List(the, program, halted)

scala> tokens.toSeq
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[String] = List(the, program, halted)
```

`Seq` is interesting. If your data will be better suited to being stored in a `List` it will turn it into a list; otherwise, it will turn it into a `Vector` (and Vectors are interesting in their own right...) - as `Seq` is a supertype of both `List` and `Vector`. If anything, you should really default to using `Vector` over other collection types unless you have a specific use case, but that's an answer to another question.

Other alternatives are of course:

```
scala> val test: Seq[String] = tokens
test: Seq[String] = List(the, program, halted)

scala> val test2: Seq[String] = for (token <- tokens) yield token
test2: Seq[String] = List(the, program, halted)

scala> val test3 = (tokens: Seq[String])
test3: Seq[String] = List(the, program, halted)

scala> val test4: Seq[String] = tokens.mkString(" ").split(" ").toSeq
test4: Seq[String] = WrappedArray(the, program, halted)
```

(Just joking about that last one)

The takeaway though is that you can just specify the variable type as `Seq[String]` and Scala will treat it as such due to how it handles `Seq`, `List`, `Vector` etc under the hood.

Comment: ...and you are also joking about the second one, because it's just a very inefficient way to apply identity function to a list ;) Which kind-of leaves you with `test` and `test3`. I also have the vague suspicion that I've already seen a solution with first and third variant somewhere^^

Comment: Second one was just fixing OP’s original attempt at a solution, but I admit it is a daft way to do it. Honestly `test3` came from me googling as many silly ways to do this and pasting them into my Terminal. I had no idea it was from this question! Imma take credit for `test` though; thought of that one all by myself. Aren’t I a smarty-pants? ;)

Comment: The problem with googling for similar questions is that the new questions are indexed almost immediately, so that when you are searching for duplicates for a question `Q0`, the first google hit leads back to the same question `Q0` ;)

Answer (score 1):

`List` is a subtype of `Seq`. You don't need any for-comprehensions at all, you only have to ascribe the type:

```
val test: Seq[String] = tokens
```

or:

```
val test = (tokens: Seq[String])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `List` extends `Seq` behind the scenes, so you do actually have a `Seq`. You can downcast at definition level.

```
val tokens: Seq[String] = List("the", "program", "halted")
```

Now to answer your question, in Scala collection conversions are often facilitated by `toXXX` methods.

```
val tokens: Seq[String] = List("the", "program", "halted").toSeq
```

In more advanced reading, look at `CanBuildFrom`, which is the magic behind the scenes.